# How would I go about powering addressable RGB LED light strip? [Arduino Nano]

Tags: arduino-nano, power, rgb-led, capacitors

The addressable RGB LED I have is WS2812B. I plan on controlling the LEDs via an Arduino nano. I have a total of 188 LEDs to supply power to.

Would I require anything between the addressable RGB LED strip and the 12v power supply?

Would I require a 1000uF capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would I require anything between the addressable RGB LED strip and the 12v power supply?

A suitable 5V regulator (assuming 5V LED strip)

> Would I require a 1000uF capacitor?

For what? A suitable 5V regulator won't need one. An unsuitable one would be improved by it, but still be unsuitable.

Comment: Regarding the 1000uF capacitor - I was just guessing from looking a diagrams which included what I would be using.

Comment: Electronics is not about guesswork. It's about hard and fast rules and formulae.